# python lambda code for aws ec2 gets stopped

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

could any one please help me the lambda code , whenever AWS Ec2 instances get stopped, we need to get the email notifications with sns. In the email we need instance name. I could able to get instance id but not the instance name.

Answer (score 1):

AWS CloudTrail allows you to identify and track EC2 instance lifecycle API calls (launch, start, stop, terminate). See [How do I use AWS CloudTrail to track API calls to my Amazon EC2 instances?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudtrail-search-api-calls/)

And you can trigger a Lambda function to run arbitrary code when CloudTrail logs certain events. See [Triggering a Lambda function with AWS CloudTrail events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-cloudtrail-example.html).

You can also [create an Amazon CloudWatch alarm that monitors an Amazon EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) and triggers a Lambda via CloudWatch Events.

Comment: Could you please help me with lambda code.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. You should make an effort to solve this yourself. There are plenty of code examples out on the web for how to write Lambda functions, how to call SNS, etc. Stack Overflow can help once you have code if it's not working but be sure to include your code and explain  clearly how it's failing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a rule in **Amazon CloudWatch Events** that:

- Triggers when an instance enters the `Stopped` state
- Sends a message to an Amazon SNS Topic

Like this:

[image: Amazon CloudWatch Events rule]

If you want to modify the message that is being sent, then configure the Rule to **trigger an AWS Lambda function** instead. Your function should:

- Extract the instance information (eg `InstanceId`) from the `event` parameter
- Call `describe-instances` to obtain the Name of the instance (presumably the Tag with a Key of `Name`)
- Publish a message to the Amazon SNS Topic